# Returning NSDictionary - Good Program Design?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

So I have a couple methods in my class that return NSDictionary has a response.
The issue is, returning NSDictionary doesn't really tell you what the dictionary holds.

I feel as if another programming wanted to use my class, he/she would find it troublesome to understand exactly what kind of information a particular method returns.

My question is: Is this considered bad programming design? Classes should be self-explanatory and reusable.

Or is this considered ok since you can determine what keys a dictionary holds, and as long as the keys are descriptive enough, it should be self-explanatory?

Comment: as long as you explain the keys clearly. apple also use this kind of approach a lot

Comment: you should create a good documentation for your methods with the exact return value. however, everybody can read the available keys (`[... allKeys]`) and everybody can get type of the `Class` of the values (`[[... valueForKey:@"<Key>"] class]`)... so there would not be problem with the `NSDictionary` as return value, it depends on how good the documentation of it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a concrete, recurring data representation, then you should really consider using a class to represent this data.

> Is this considered bad programming design?

It can be, or a dictionary can be the best solution in some cases. It really depends on the data you return, and how it affects the client. If you can simplify the program (in the big picture) by creating a class to represent this data, then the dictionary is surely the wrong solution.

A typical indication is the noise the client goes through when receiving your data -- do they need to do a bunch of dynamic key and type testing all over the place? Then it is likely a good candidate that your program can be simplified and easier to maintain if it is represented as a proper class.

Comment: So I guess the general consensus is that, if it can be simplified by creating a class do that. Otherwise it's ok as long as it's well documented.

Comment: @khaliq well, it's not *just* that. maintenance and change are also big considerations. i find there's less that is likely to go wrong with classes. the class is often easier to change, maintain, and it can introduce type safety. if you need to change, add, or deprecate something -- the compiler can really step in and make sure your clients are using the object correctly. as well, typesafety can go a very long way. it's rare that I use the dictionary form in production code, and it's rare that it has more than a few fields.

Comment: I guess you can't best building a class, since it's reusable and more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the answer is: IT DEPENDS

If you use dictionaries instead of objects all over you project it is a bad design.
If you use them only in some specific situations like e.g. list of settings or similiar case it might be OK.

If this code will be used by other people make sure you document it somewhere so people know what will they get from there and have an idea what the dictionary actually represents.

(I was once working on a project where everyting was dictionary with now real documenation so the only way to know what's in dictionary was to go to debug mode, set breakpoints and look in debugger to see values. You don't want to do this to people.)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I generally try to design my code to a point where it's easy enough for other people to determine its purpose, without having to lose their sanity in the process.